# How to upload an image on Facebook without staging it in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-opengraph

This is my code so far to post a custom story with a local Image. The Image shows in the Share Dialog but the post doesn't complete.

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];

        object.provisionedForPost = YES;
        object[@"title"]       = @"";
        object[@"type"]        = @"socialsnooker:game_of_snooker";
        object[@"description"] = @"";
        object[@"url"]         = @"http://socialsnooker.com/opengraph.php";
        object[@"image"]       = @[@{@"url": newImage, @"user_generated" : @"false" }];

        NSArray* images = @[@{@"url": newImage, @"user_generated" : @"true" }];

        id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

        [action setObject:images forKey:@"image"];
        [action setObject:object forKey:@"game_of_snooker"];
        [action setTags:@[opponent]];

        // Tag a place using the place's id
        id<FBGraphPlace> place = (id<FBGraphPlace>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
        [place setObjectID:@"36397646443"]; // Q-Masters
        [action setPlace:place];

        // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
        FBOpenGraphActionParams *params = [[FBOpenGraphActionParams alloc] init];
        params.action = action;
        params.actionType = @"socialsnooker:score";

        // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
        if([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:params]) {
            // Show the share dialog
            [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                                  actionType:@"socialsnooker:score"
                                         previewPropertyName:@"game_of_snooker"
                                                     handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                         if(error) {
                                                             // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                             // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                             NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                                         } else {
                                                             // Success
                                                             NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                                         }
                                                     }];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Not Installed"
                                                            message:@"The Facebook App couldn't be found on your phone."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
```

[Here is a Screenshot of the Share Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDIVA.png)

The Image does show up in the Share Dialog and I do get a post ID in return but the action does not get posted on Facebook.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is all fine there is no doubts about it. I faced the same problem earlier and when I googled it, it took me to Facebook Developers page where it mentioned that open graph objects, stories and action won't be published on user's wall until you submit the app for review on Facebook. Though I can't find the link again, but as soon as I get the link I'll share it. So if you want to see the user post submit your app for review.

Comment: I came across the same scenario as Aditya Mathur described. If you go into your own profile and find the "view activities" it should list something like "XYZ has shared a story" but it won't be publicly visible on your timeline or wall to your friends. Facebook doesn't want anyone to be able to post custom stories, they need to approve the verbs and such in case of objectionable content.

Comment: I can see the story on my wall if I stage the Image on Facebook as an object and then post the story. But for staging an Image I need publish_actions permissions which I would like to avoid and I can avoid them if I can directly upload an Image, which is not happening for me.

Comment: I just got the App approved on Facebook and the posts still aren't showing up on my Timeline or Activity Log even though I get a success result on the Post. Any further suggestions?